# swift: why need to conform equatable when overload the "==" operator?

Tags: swift, operators, overloading, equatable

I'm learning swift and read a topic about operator overloading in extensions, which likes:

```
extension StreetAddress: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: StreetAddress, rhs: StreetAddress) -> Bool {
        return
            lhs.number == rhs.number &&
            lhs.street == rhs.street &&
            lhs.unit == rhs.unit
    }
}
```

But how i can know i need to adopt the Equatable?

I tried to remove that protocol and the function works the same. 
No warnings or errors be reported. 
Why?

Comment: Conforming to `Equatable` requires that you implement `==`, but implementing `==`  does not require that you conform to `Equatable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable):

> To adopt the Equatable protocol, implement the equal-to operator (==)
>   as a static method of your type

so implementing `Equatable` means you **must** overload the `==` operator, hence this is a build error:

```
extension StreetAddress: Equatable {
}
```

Overloading the == operator doesn't require and is not **strictly** related to `Equatable`, eg:

```
class StreetAddress {
    var theAddress:String?

    static func == (lhs: StreetAddress, rhs: StreetAddress) -> Bool {
        return lhs.theAddress?.lowercased() == rhs.theAddress?.lowercased()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I also found the answer in reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Please feel free to up-vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Interesting. In Version 11.2 beta 2 (11B44), the code compiles without having to add Equatable.